# Python exclude special characters and numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a better way to do this?

I want the code to detect numbers and special characters and print:

"numbers not allowed" / "special characters not allowed"

```
while True:
try:
    x = input('Enter an alphabet:')
except ValueError:
    print('sorry i do not understand that')
    continue
if x in ('1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'):
    print('Numbers not allowed')
    continue
else:
    break
if x in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
print ('{} is a vowel'.format(x))

elif x in ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'):
print ('{} is a vowel in CAPS'.fotmat(x))
else:
print('{} is a consonant'.format(x))
```

Comment: That first try-except seems pointless... and what exactly are you trying to validate? Only letters and spaces?

Comment: You can `import string` and check to see if `x in string.ascii_letters` and for numbers check if `x in string.digits`

Comment: You should the a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `string` library.

Here is some psuedocode, which assumes that the input is one character at a time:

```
import string
x = input('Enter an alphabet:')
if x in string.digits:
    print('Numbers not allowed')
elif x not in string.ascii_letters:
    print('Not a letter')
```

`string.ascii_letters` is a string that contains all the uppercase and lowercase letters:

```
print(string.ascii_letters)
#'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Likewise, `string.digits` is a string that contains all of the digits:

```
print(string.digits)
#'0123456789'
```

Comment: This is the best solution. But as an alternative you can always `raise ValurError` manually instead of just using `print`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it a couple of ways but the pythonic method seems to me to be like so:

```
if any(char in string.punctuation for char in x) or any(char.isdigit() for char in x):
    print("nope")
```

Comment: Why call `set`? `string.punctuation` already only contains unique values.

Comment: because you can easily add something like .replace() if you want to allow specific chars.

Comment: I'm not following your logic. In this case `any(char in set(string.punctuation) for char in x)` and `any(char in string.punctuation for char in x)` produce the same output. In what case would it be different?

Comment: You are correct, I was thinking of something else at the time. I should not switch from node projects to python questions.

Answer (score 0):

May be this code does the job.

```
while True:
x = ord(input('Enter an alphabet:')[0])
if x in range(ord('0'), ord('9')):
    print('Numbers not allowed')
    continue
if x not in range(ord('A'), ord('z')):
    print('Symbols not allowed')
    continue
if chr(x) in 'aeiou':
    print('{} is a vowel'.format(chr(x)))
elif chr(x) in 'AEIOU':
    print('{} is a vowel in CAPS'.format(chr(x)))
else:
    print('{} is a consonant'.format(chr(x)))
continue
```

We select numbers, deselect whatever character except letters and then does the job.